# How to hide button after the button is manual added in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have added button manually in for loop, after that, how to hide or change the button and hide label?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 170, 150.0, 30.0);
[button setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];

UILabel *lblFileName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblFileName.text = [[objectArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"fileName"];
lblFileName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:lblFileName];

-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
    // hide the button or change title button and hide label
}
```

Comment: You want to hide all labels or label related to particular button.

Comment: label related to particular button

Comment: Try with my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u are adding `buttons & labels` in `for loop`, then try following solution.

```
button.tag = i + 1;//0 is default tag for all views.
lblFileName.tag = i + 1;

-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setHidden:YES];// hide the button
    btn.titleLabel.text = [[objectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] valueForKey:@"fileName"];

     //Get the label of selected button using button tag.
    [[self.view viewWithTag:[sender tag]] setHidden:YES];

}
```

Comment: thx you. if label, then how change it after click button. UILabel *lblFileName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                lblFileName.text = [[objectArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"fileName"];
                lblFileName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

Comment: objectArray is the dict which contains the label titles which u mentioned in your question for setting the label text.

Comment: if i want to hide the label after click button??

Comment: Edit your question & explain exactly what you want.

Comment: if click first button, then error, if click another button then not problem

Comment: set the tag i+1 bcz other views also has default tag as 0, so it creating a prbm.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
    // hide the button or change title button
[button setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In myAction:(id)sender sender is your Button.

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender {
       [sender setHidden:YES];
}
```

But in this case you cannot make the button visible anymore, because you have no reference to it. I think it would be better to create a property for the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender
{

   btn.hidden=YES;
}
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Other answerers have already shown how `sender` is the button you want, butif you want to access the button in an different method (for example, if you want to make it visible again) you will need to create a property on the object that created the button.

To do so, put this in your class `@interface`:

```
@property (strong) UIButton *myButton;
```

And `@synthesize` it in your `@implementation`:

```
@implementation WhateverClass
@synthesize myButton = _myButton;
```

Then you can set the property to your custom button:

```
self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 170, 150.0, 30.0);
[self.myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.myButton];
```

and access it anywhere (after it has been created) like so:

```
-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Pressed!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: cannot like that, my code is in for loop, if 100, how to create 100 button

Comment: Okay, that's probably something that you should have stated in the question. If that's what you're doing, @Girish's answer would probably work best.

Answer (score 0):

Give unique tag for each button and label like Girish said.No two tags should not be same.

Consider you have 10 button and 10 label. Then give tag for button 1 to 10 and label 11 to 20.

Then on your method you can access any label or button using corresponding tag.

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *label=(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:11];
```